# Hardware For Emitting Specific Sound Frequency

Tags: arduino, sound, ultrasound, piezo-buzzer

I need a battery-powered hardware setup for emitting  a specific frequency or a range of frequencies, in the range of 17kHz-20kHz. It should be picked up by microphones from at least 8 meters away (not sure how to convert this to Dbm).
The strength of the signal has to be relatively stable for at least one hour.

I have several questions:

1. Is there a hardware solution that does this?
2. If I would want to make one myself, what would I need? Let's say I use Arduino with a buzzer, what buzzer and battery would you recommend?
3. Any other suggestions or considerations I did not provide and should consider?

Thanks!

Edit:
I fixed 17-20Hz to 17-20kHz. Do waves in this Frequency still come out squared when toggling buzzer input?

Comment: Haven't you answered your number (1) with number (2)? The remaining stuff is off-topic

Comment: If there is an existing simple, reliable and inexpensive solution, I prefer to buy it.

Comment: "at lower frequencies of course" ? Did you mean to write 20kHz?

Comment: At such a low frequency, if you actually want to emit the desired frequency not its odd multiples, you will need a sine wave source not a square wave.  You can do this with an MCU, but you need to build a direct digital synthesizer and have some kind of analog output, possibly PWM with a lowpass filter.

Comment: Will your detector be a square meter of 1/4" thick aluminium? Should response well to only 20 cycles per second.

Comment: Big apologies, I meant 17-20kHz. I edited the question.

Comment: Take care where you mount this repellent device - an 8-meter range could damage hearing of teenagers who wander too close.

Comment: @Ilans - Are you sure about the frequency?  That is too close to the border of human hearing to be broadly applicable.  In other words, many people may not even hear it, and say that you want it to be audible at 24 feet away, but you did not specify the target audience -- children? retirement home? football crowd? jackhammer operators?  We might need to know if it's general population.  Are these your specifications, or somebody else's, because we may have to "manage expectations" if it's a customer (or assignment, or relative, etc.)  One source I googled suggested 1KHz. Please fill us in. Thx

Comment: Is this a repellent device?  I was assuming you WANT it to be heard by humans. You said, "It should be heard (at lower frequencies of course) from at least 8 meters away (not sure how to convert this to Dbm)."  Please tell us what the "lower frequencies" means, and what the target audience of the tone is (i.e., WHO should be hearing this sound). Thx

Comment: This is not a repellent device or anything similar. When I said 'heard' I mean it's Dbm should be sufficient to be picked up by microphones at that distance. Will edit the question.

Comment: Micro-controller with I2S interface. Audio DAC or CODEC with ability to drive 16 or 8 Ohm loudspeaker. 8 or 16 Ohm loudspeaker. Power source of some sourt. Code on micro-controller that can feed sine wave to loudspeaker. I can't hear 17kHz very well. But some people can. This will drive them crazy.

Comment: For a purchased solution (which would be off-topic) see @Elmesito 's solution suggestion. I think this will work pretty well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, 20KHz is pretty quick with a 1/2 period of 25uS. Code updated to reflect that.

```
byte outputPin = 2;

void set(){
  pinMode (outputPin, OUTPUT);
}

void loop(){
  while (1){  // added to avoid some of the timing jitter caused by behind the scenes loop() processing
    PIND = 0b00000100; // toggle D2 by writing to the input port
    delayMicroseconds (24); // micro
  }
}
```

micros() are updated every 64 clock cycles, so 4uS granularity.  If you use anything but 24 or 28, I think it gets rounded up or down to a multiple of 4.  Have to check with an oscilliscope.  The while() code adds a little processing, so 20 or 24 may get you pretty close.

I browsed Digikey and did not see any piezos that did 20 KHz, you may need to use a speaker tweeter to get that range.

Comment: A square wave is a poor solution to the problem.  Given how hard it is to couple energy at low frequencies, most of what this will radiate will be energy at odd multiples of the desired frequency.

Comment: Further, experiment with generated waveforms in audacity shows that a 20 Hz square wave will sound like discrete thumps, not a tone.  Even a sine wave source played through cheap PC speakers will sound as much like pulses as a tone, but starting with a square wave is *completely* wrong, no matter how good your speakers are.

Comment: So add a little lowpass filtering, smooth it out a little.  Or add a DAC and synthesize the waveform from levels stored in memory.

Comment: Jesus, sorry, I meant 17-20kHz. I updated the question.

Comment: Also, from reading your replies, I understand that a buzzer is not a good solution because it offers a square wave, instead of a sine. Is it still relevant to 17-20kHz?

Comment: With the  (revised) 3rd harmonics in the 50 - 60 KHz range signal energy there probably won't make it into the physical realm.   Driving a little pieze disc directly you should be fine, however some types of power amplifiers might not like the overtone content... or a piezo as a load.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest solution is to buy a cheap DDS circuit from China (just search on Aliexpress), configure it to output a sine wave at the frequency you have mentioned and connect the output into an amplified speaker.

Alternatively to a DDS, you can use the output of your smartphone; there are several signal generator apps available for free.

The size of the speaker depends very much on the distance you want to cover.

Comment: Big apologies, I meant 17-20kHz. I edited the question.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. I have edited the response to reflect the change in the question